# How animate pie chart jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jqplot and make a pie chart.
How I can animate it?
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    plot = jQuery.jqplot('chart', [
        [
            ['a', 32.1],
            ['b', 17.0]
        ]
    ], {
           seriesColors: ["#ff0070", "#00557d"],
           seriesDefaults: {
               shadow: false,
               renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
               rendererOptions: {
                   fill: false,
                   sliceMargin: 10,
                   showDataLabels: true,
                   startAngle: 120,
                   dataLabelThreshold: 5,
                   dataLabelPositionFactor: 0.6
               }
           },
           legend: {
               show: true
           }
    });
});
```

How can I animate open this chart on circle?